# Error converting bytecode to dex and 1 more

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

Hey I tried to add AdMob to my Android Studio project, so I had to add these lines:

```
dependencies {

    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now if I try to launch my application I'm getting these errors:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqq$zza;
```

And

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

My build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Maybe the versions are wrong?
Or did I miss something?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'
```

and now it's working fine!